# Session is not clearing properly even after logout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an application built on ASP. NET MVC . For authentication I have used form authentication. But I am facing a problem related to session in logout . In logged out Inhave flow all the recommendations like Session Abandon, Session Clear after calling the FormsAuth. Signout method.But after logging out if user made a request which he captured by the user using a tool before logging out the request is successful which is not desired because before the last request I have called the logout as I have mentioned above.
How to solve this issue?

Thanks
Utpal Maity